# BigQuery dynamic query - equivalent of SQL Server sp_executesql

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to run a dynamic query in `BigQuery`?

I have a `SELECT` query that returns a valid `BigQuery` query statement,
I want to run it without making an additional query from my code.

SQL Server [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) does that well.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL in Google Bigquery is in beta, and was announced in May 2020.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate